# Window lock - help identifying

Tags: windows

Does anyone know what type of lock this is called - this is on a window that slides open vertically.  I really like them but don't know how to find them and my searches haven't yielded any luck so far.  It's positioned a few inches above middle to prevent a window from opening far enough for someone to get in yet still allow airflow.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed @isherwood's recommendation and it turns out that they don't call this a lock but rather an opening control device - it's Andersen Windows part #9130514.

The Andersen Windows parts site has an option to look up parts by product ID which is on the sticker in the upper part of the window frame.